# JS function names compression

Tags: javascript, minify

I can't seem to find a JS minifier that performs function names compression. For example, given this pseudo-code:

```
//non pure function
function test() {
   //do some computations...
   return <whatever>;
}

alert(test());
```

Would then, for example, be minified to this:

```
function t(){//do some computations... return <whatever>}alert(t());
```

So far I have not found any JS tool that does this sort of compression. Does anyone know any?

Comment: uglify js is a good one

Comment: @JordanHendrix yeah it is, but from what I've seen it does not compress function names...

Comment: it does, you have to turn on mangling...same thing with the answer below

Comment: well, I have just tested with this online tool (http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/#demo), and even with magle option checked, the function names don't get compressed

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use UglifyJS it will not mangle top-level names, or names available to the global scope.

You can still achieve this if you turn on the -mt or --mangle-toplevel flag in the command line like so:

Here is some code I posted in the demo link you provided:

```
function longfunctionname(a) {
  return function reallylongfunctionname(b) {
    return a + b;
  };
}
```

Here is the mangled code without top level mangling turned on:

```
function longfunctionname(n){return function u(n){return n}}
```

As you can see the top level function is not mangled, but the inner function is

go here to read more: http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/

Comment: Ok great, thanks, I have put my code inside an IIFE and, with the mangle option checked, the function names got compressed

Comment: nice, thats the quick fix!

Answer (score -2):

Definitely! You can use a task runner (i.e. Grunt or Gulp) to assist, but the process you are describing is normally defined as "uglifying" or "mangling" JS. Check out [gulp-uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) or [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify) to get started.

EDIT: Per comments on this answer, using a task runner is not necessary, as you can use [UglifyJS](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS) on its own.

Comment: you dont need a task runner, it helps to run multiple tasks but its not needed

Comment: Good call. Updating answer.

Comment: So, why aren't function names being compressed on this online demo tool of uglifyjs (with mangle option checked)? http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/#demo

Comment: @lalalalalala https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#mangler-options top-level are defaulted to not mangle, which makes sense since you may want to reference top level functions outside of the script they are running in.

Answer (score -2):

Its good habit to write code that doesn't pollute the global space. By wrapping in an anonymous function the code will minify and will not collide with other global references.

```
(function (){
   function test() {
    //do some computations...
    return "something";
   }
   alert(test());
})();
```

If you run UglifyJs with --mangle the output will look like this

```
!function(){function t(){return"something"}alert(t())}();
```

I used https://skalman.github.io/UglifyJS-online/ to get generated UglifyJs code